# onmouseover two divs one visable one hidden on hover I want to make the second div visible and the first hidden like a switch

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

trying to onmouseover show the first div but hide the second, then on hover show the second div but hide the first. sorry im being a noob not good at javascript.can anyone solve this for me please i would very much appreciate it. It seems I've left some of that code out as i do not know how to apply it, like onmouseover and onmouseout if you could explain your answers that would be great too..

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<body>
<div id="placeholder" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('blink').style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('blink').style.display = 'none';">
 <div id="show">
## Heading ##
 </div>
 <div id="blink">
 <p> some text </p>
 </div>
 </div>
</html>
</body>

 css
  #placement{display:block;}
 #show{display:block;}
 .blink{
  position:relative;
 left:100px;
 width:450px;
height:515px;
background:#000;
padding:15px;
color:white;

}
 #blink:hover #blink{
display:block;
visibility:visible;
}

  .hide_show{
position:absolute;
left:15px;
right:15px;
padding:0;
margin:0;
text-align:left;}
```

Comment: _"...then on hover..."_ - Do you mean "then on _mouseout_"?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, guess you what you want is to display the heading lines in default, and when mouse over, the hidden text would show up?
Try following: (basically you need to set the #blink div to invisible at first. also id name incorrect for placeholder (not placement)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<style>
#placeholder{display:block;}
 #show{display:block;}
 .blink{
  position:relative;
 left:100px;
 width:450px;
height:515px;
background:#000;
padding:15px;
color:white;
display:none;
}
 #blink:hover #blink{
display:block;
visibility:visible;
}
  .hide_show{
position:absolute;
left:15px;
right:15px;
padding:0;
margin:0;
text-align:left;}
</style>
        <body>
        <div id="placeholder" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('blink').style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('blink').style.display = 'none';">
         <div id="show">## Heading ##</div>
         <div id="blink"><p> some text </p></div>
        </div>
        </html>
    </body>
```

Comment: I need ten rep point to post images how do I get ten points of reputation to show my images

Comment: actually if you just paste my previous answer to your editor it WILL work

Comment: Thanks it works,  is it possible to make a hidden div with display block visible the other way around say its invisible then you want it visible like display: none; display: block; visibility: visible. As when I tried to do it, the placeholder invisible wouldn't be visible.

Comment: WOw yeah finally figured it.. Works Great thank you in abundance.. Top chap..happy very happy..

Comment: Mind select my answer if you are happy :)

Answer (score 0):

I can help you now problem just let me better understand your question when someone hovers with their mouse over div.show u want that div to how and .blink to hide? and then when someone hovers over .blink u want that to show and hide .show?

Comment: yes that be even better solution sounds great, still trying to get it to hide wont work on firefox..